# Delphi: REST Request with BASIC authentication

Tags: rest, delphi, request, basic-authentication

I'm using TRESTClient/THTTPBasicAuthenticator/TRESTRequest/TRESTResponse to get data from a server.

With response Ok (200), instead of receiving JSON data, I get as content this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- function redirectToIndex()
{       
var adresse = window.location.pathname.split('/');      
var httpURL = window.location.hostname + "/" + "app"; // redirect to root
var httpsURL = "https://" + httpURL;
window.location = httpsURL;
}
redirectToIndex();  //-->
```

This is when **TRESTRequest.Accept** is empty. If I change for **TRESTRequest.Accept**:= '*application/json*', I get an error

```
406 - Not Acceptable
```

Could you tell me what's wrong with my request?

Comment: The returned response looks like a HTML that contains redirection script to other resource located at `https://{target-server}/app`. REST client does not follow such redirections. You should either make requests to that resource or use some other appropriate URI. Refer to vendor API documentation to find that out.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I was indeed pointing the the wrong URI which does not include my subdomain. I do have another problem with error 401: unauthorized access - Your API key is wrong.   At this moment, I am adding the API Key in the header with 'authorization:basic XXXX-XXXX-XXXX. Is it the correct way?

Comment: You didn't provide any code regarding authentication. If you do, be sure to blank out any sensitive information. You could also edit your question and quote from the documentation so it is clear to us what kind of authentication does the endpoint require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Peter.
I managed to clarify with the API support the BASIC Authentication using the correct login/password . The documentation was inaccurate.
Access is now working as expected.